# SQL Server view to provide a consistent table structure using JSON

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, entity-framework

I want to create a read only view with the following columns:

```
Id            - Unique integer
ActivityKind  - Identifies what is in PayloadAsJson. Could be an int, char whatever
PayloadAsJson - Record from corresponding table presented as JSON
```

The reason for this is that I have a number of tables that have different structures that I want to UNION and present in some kind of date order. So for example:

**Table1**

```
Id Date        EmailSubject   EmailRecipient
-- ----------- -------------- ---------------
 1 2014-01-01  "Hello World"  "me@there.com"
 2 2014-01-02  "Hello World2" "me@there.com"
```

**Table2**

```
Id Date        SensorId SensorName
-- ----------- -------- ------------------
 1 2014-01-01         1 "Some Sensor Name"
```

I would have SQL similair to the following for the view of:

```sql
SELECT Date, 'E' AS ActivityKind, <SPCallToGetJSONForThisRecord> AS PayloadAsJson
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Date, 'S' AS ActivityKind, <SPCallToGetJSONForThisRecord> AS PayloadAsJson
FROM Table2
ORDER BY Date
```

and I want the view to look like:

```
1, "E", "{ "Id": 1, "Date": "2014-01-01", "EmailSubject": "Hello World", "EmailRecipient": me@there.com" }"
2, "S", "{ "Id": 1, "Date": "2014-01-01", "SensorId": 1, "SensorName": "Some Sensor Name" }"
3, "E", "{ "Id": 2, "Date": "2014-01-01", "EmailSubject": "Hello World2", "EmailRecipient": me@there.com" }"
```

The rationale here is that:

- I can use the DB server to produce the view by doing whatever SQL needed
- This data is going to be read only on the client side
- By having a consistent view structure namely Id, ActivityKind, Payload any time I want to add some additional tables in I can do so, client code would be modified to handle decoding the JSON based on ActivityKind

Now there are many Stored Procedure implementations to convert an entire SQL result to JSON http://jaminquimby.com/joomla253/servers/95-sql/sql-2008/145-code-tsql-convert-query-to-json, but what I am struggling with is:

1. Getting the uniue running sequence for the entire view
2. The actual implementation of  because this has to do it on a record by record basis.

In short I am looking for a solution that shows me how to create the view to the above requirements. All pointers and help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a need to do this all in SQL. You could pull back the records from SQL into C# objects, and use them and JSON.NET to convert them to JSON -- absolutely no need to make a JSON Serializer for SQL Server.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker There are a couple of reasons: 1) Not all the tables to be included are to be the same structure, so all I would end up doing is keep on extending the view sideways to add new fields 2) By performing the processing on the DB server side I a) do not have to do it on the App Server and thus spread the load, b) I do not have to pull down excessive amounts of data to the AppServer (as the view would be very sparse because of all the additional fields) - both a) & b) would result in significant performance improvements with the size of the data loads in question

Comment: 1) Not relevant to George's comment.  2) Most if not all DAO/ORMs will run this server side a) performance should be close if not exactly the same b) you can specify which fields you want.

Comment: @TheEdge Not sure the view is your best bet here; but still not relevant, as Erik says, any ORM Worth its salt (You tagged EF, and it does this) will let you pull back relationships without worrying about the physical structure of the table. The Database is not the best way to do this; nor is it even a mediocre way to do this. It's not meant to do this. It's far cheaper to scale App servers than it is to try to scale a Database Server; especially if you get this working in SQL.  What are your DB box specs? What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I will be wanting all the fields on a particular date range. So to me it seems better to keep the SQL the central place to composite all the disparate record types into something that can be parsed on the client.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for your insights. I agree that scaling the AppServer is easier than the DBServer. The tipping point for me is that ultimately the view will be "composited" with a large number of disparate tables into a particular date / date range. This is still best done on the DB server and the ORM (yes EF) can then restrict by date and/or doing a LIKE into the JSON. Because ultimately we will be looking at a date range on the client so we want all the data to come down for the date/date range and the ORM won't be useful in optomising at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not getting into the debate about whether this should be done in the database or not, it seemed like an interesting puzzle, and more and more people seem to be wanting at least simple JSON translation at the DB level. So, there are a couple of ideas.

The first idea is to have SQL Server do most of the work for us by turning the row into XML via the `FOR XML` clause. A simple, attribute-based XML representation of a row is very similar in nature to the JSON structure; it just needs a little transformin'. While the parsing could be done purely in T-SQL via `PATINDEX`, etc, but that just complicates things. So, a somewhat simple Regular Expression Replace makes it rather simple to change the `name="value"` structure into `"name": "value"`. The following example uses a RegEx function that is available in the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of, but RegEx_Replace is in the Free version).

And just as I finished that I remembered that you can do transformations via the `.query()` function against an `XML` field or variable, and use [FLWOR Statement and Iteration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx) to cycle through the attributes. So I added another column for this second use of the XML intermediate output, but this is done in pure T-SQL as opposed to requiring CLR in the case of RegEx. I figured it was easiest to place in the same overall test setup rather than repeat the majority of it just to change a few lines.

A third idea is to go back to SQLCLR, but to create a scalar function that takes in the table name and ID as parameters. You can then make use of the "Context Connection" which is the in-process connection (hence fast) and build a Dynamic SQL statement of "SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE ID = {value}" (obviously check inputs for single-quotes and dashes to avoid SQL Injection). When you call SqlDataReader, you can not only step through each field easily, but you then also have insight into the datatype of each field and can determine if it is numeric, and if so, then don't put the double-quotes around the value in the output. [If I have time tomorrow or over the weekend I will try to put something together.]

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON; SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [EmailSubject] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  [EmailRecipient] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1, '2014-01-01', N'Hello World', N'me@here.com');
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (2, '2014-03-02', N'Hello World2', N'me@there.com');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [SensorId] INT NOT NULL,
  [SensorName] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1, '2014-01-01', 1, N'Some Sensor Name');
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (2, '2014-02-01', 34, N'Another > Sensor Name');
---------------------------------------
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT  tmp.[Date], 'E' AS ActivityKind,
          (SELECT t2.* FROM @Table1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = tmp.ID FOR XML RAW('wtf'))
             AS [SourceForJSON]
  FROM    @Table1 tmp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  tmp.[Date], 'S' AS ActivityKind,
          (SELECT t2.*, NEWID() AS [g=g] FROM @Table2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = tmp.ID
             FOR XML RAW('wtf')) AS [SourceForJSON]
  FROM    @Table2 tmp
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.[Date]) AS [Seq],
       cte.ActivityKind,
       cte.SourceForJSON,
       N'{' +
           REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
                    SUBSTRING(SQL#.RegEx_Replace(cte.SourceForJSON,
                        N' ([^ ="]+)="([^"]*)"',
                        N' "$1": "$2",', -1, 1, N'IgnoreCase'),
                     6, 4000),
                N'",/>', '"}'),
                N'&gt;', N'>'),
                N'&lt;', N'<') AS [JSONviaRegEx],
       N'{' + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
         CONVERT(XML, cte.SourceForJSON).query('
           let $end := local-name((/wtf/@*)[last()])
           for $item in /wtf/@*
           return concat("&quot;",
                local-name($item),
                "&quot;: &quot;",
                data($item),
                "&quot;",
                if (local-name($item) != $end) then ", " else "")
          ')), N'&gt;', N'>') + N'}' AS [JSONviaXQuery]
FROM   cte;
```

Please keep in mind that in the above SQL, the cte query can be easily encapsulated in a View, and the transformation (whether via SQLCLR/RegEx or XML/XQuery) can be encapsulated in a T-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function and used in the main SELECT (the one that selects from the cte) via `CROSS APPLY`.

**EDIT:**
And speaking of encapsulating the XQuery into a function and calling via `CROSS APPLY`, here it is:

The function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JSONfromXMLviaXQuery (@SourceRow XML)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT   N'{'
         + REPLACE(
             CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @SourceRow.query('
                      let $end := local-name((/wtf/@*)[last()])
                      for $item in /wtf/@*
                      return concat("&quot;",
                                    local-name($item),
                                    "&quot;: &quot;",
                                    data($item),
                                   "&quot;",
                                   if (local-name($item) != $end) then "," else "")
                      ')
                    ),
             N'&gt;',
             N'>')
         + N'}' AS [TheJSON];
```

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [EmailSubject] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  [EmailRecipient] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '2014-01-01', N'Hello World', N'me@here.com');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (2, '2014-03-02', N'Hello World2', N'me@there.com');

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [SensorId] INT NOT NULL,
  [SensorName] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (1, '2014-01-01', 1, N'Some Sensor Name');
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (2, '2014-02-01', 34, N'Another > Sensor Name');
```

The view (or what would be if I wasn't using temp tables):

```sql
--CREATE VIEW dbo.GetMyStuff
--AS
    ;WITH cte AS
    (
      SELECT  tmp.[Date], 'E' AS ActivityKind,
              (SELECT t2.* FROM #Table1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = tmp.ID
                 FOR XML RAW('wtf'), TYPE) AS [SourceForJSON]
      FROM    #Table1 tmp
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  tmp.[Date], 'S' AS ActivityKind,
              (SELECT t2.*, NEWID() AS [g=g] FROM #Table2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = tmp.ID
                 FOR XML RAW('wtf'), TYPE) AS [SourceForJSON]
      FROM    #Table2 tmp
    )
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.[Date]) AS [Seq],
           cte.ActivityKind,
           json.TheJSON
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY dbo.JSONfromXMLviaXQuery(cte.SourceForJSON) json;
```

The results:

```
Seq  ActivityKind  TheJSON
1    E             {"ID": "1", "Date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00", "EmailSubject": "Hello World", "EmailRecipient": "me@here.com"}
2    S             {"ID": "1", "Date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00", "SensorId": "1", "SensorName": "Some Sensor Name", "g_x003D_g": "3AE13983-6C6C-49E8-8E9D-437DAA62F910"}
3    S             {"ID": "2", "Date": "2014-02-01T00:00:00", "SensorId": "34", "SensorName": "Another > Sensor Name", "g_x003D_g": "7E760F9D-2B5A-4FAA-8625-7B76AA59FE82"}
4    E             {"ID": "2", "Date": "2014-03-02T00:00:00", "EmailSubject": "Hello World2", "EmailRecipient": "me@there.com"}
```

Comment: @srutky What a great answer! It does just what I want. And I really appreciate the "lets not getting into the debate of whether this should be done".

Comment: @TheEdge Thanks and yer welcome. Do you still want the CLR thing since it is the only way to get the datatype, hence the ability to _not_ quote numeric types? It will be a few days but shouldn't be too difficult. Regarding the "should / shouldnt" debate: I am very pragmatic. There are ideals to strive for and reality is mostly grey area. "Never denormalize or use CURSORs!" Skill is knowing what the pros/cons are and how/when to choose which. It's fine to suggest a risky approach **IF** the risks are mentioned. I keep hearing "don't use CLR" yet http://www.SQLsharp.com/ has helped thousands :).

Comment: I don't need the CLR implementation thanks. It would be nice, but I don't want to have to manage and deploy something additional so will deal with the decoding issue within .NET itself client side.